# Touchscreen swipe to switch between virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, microsoft-surface, virtual-desktop, multiple-desktop

I want to change between my desktops by using 2-3-4 finger gestures on my Microsoft Surface Go. At the moment I can open up the on-screen touchpad (yes, that's a thing apparently), and I can use 4 fingers to swipe between desktops.

However, I simply cannot find a solution, that allows me to switch between desktops ***only*** using the touchscreen.

Are there any solutions? I would hate to write my own software to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. I grabbed a copy of [TouchMe Gesture Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/touchme-gesture-studio/9wzdncrdg0l8?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), which prompted me to install [their TouchMe engine](http://www.yasharbahman.com/get-touchme-engine/). Since I only need 2 gestures, it's free to use.

The license lasts for 32 days, but I am apparently free to use it with up to 3 gestures after that. Neat. I'll probably end up purchasing a license, though.

Answer (score 0):

As an update on this older question:

[GestureSign](https://gesturesign.win/#/) works quite well for me. No need for a licence.

You can limit the gestures in detail to mouse, touchpad, pen and touchscreen. Helped me with switching desktops just by using the touchscreen and leaving the gesture-controle of my touchpad untouched.

Answer (score -1):

Press the windows button, then press 'tab'.
That should do it.

Comment: OP clearly asked for a touchscreen gesture to accomplish this, not keyboard shortcuts. Please read the question and answer the question that is asked, not the one you hear in your own head.